# How do I use ngFor to loop over a classes Map variable in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a class called myMap that has a variable called navList: Map<string, string> which hold multiple key values. This class is located in my ts file. I'm trying to loop over the navList values in the html file using ngFor but I am not sure how it is done. Sorry I didn't provide screen shots of my code, I am fairly new and don't know how to do it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: use .values() which is an Inerrable over the map values

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `KeyValuePipe`.
Transforms Object or Map into an array of key value pairs.

```
{{ input_expression | keyvalue [ : compareFn ] }}
```

Example:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of map | keyvalue">
  {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>
```

[read more](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe#description)